# UICollectionView scroll to bottom do not reveal the entire item

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I have a Screen like this which is built in interface builder:

[image]

The control at the bottom is a `UICollectionView` and the other two are a UIButton and a segmentedControl. They sit on a  UIView which is a child of the `UIController's` view but has the same frame. In my code, I add the `UIViewController` to a `UINavigationController` so there will be a `UINavigationBar` on the top of the screen. I can set the auto layout constraint to force the top of this screen to move below the navigationbar.  However when I scroll down the `UICollectionView` I couldn't scroll to the bottom to view the rest of the items. I can only see half size of the last two items. 
I have updated the code and put some log in `viewDidAppear`:

> UICollectionView frame height = 527.000000
>
> View frame = 504.000000

So the `UICollectionView's` height is bigger than the view's height. I want the collection view to fit right in both 3.5" screen and 4" screen.

Any idea what I have done wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: In the `viewDidAppear` method, print out the `frame` of the view controller's view and the UICollectionView.  I'm guessing the UICollectionView extends off the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your collection view's height is exceeding that of the frame, try to reduce the height of your collection view which fits that of your UIView's height - your collection view's yOrigin.

Comment: My collectionview's bottom is in line with the UIViewController's view. If I reduce the height of collectionview it will display a blank space at the bottom.

Comment: as per your edit, you are getting height of collection view greater than view's height. Try to reduce the height of collection view once..

Comment: I've told you I have tried that before. The app has been online for a few months but it only works fine on 3.5" screen. I just found out on 4" screen there is very big blank space at the bottom that's why I need to look for a better way to resolve this problem.

Comment: for this you can reduce the height based on screen height, ie, if it is 480, then reduce the height else not.
If you don't want to do this, then you will have to go with constraints setting..

Comment: I don't want to do this because it doesn't fit all screens. I've ended up making the collectionview full screen so that the auto layout constraints don't behave unexpectedly. For example when I set top space of the UICollectionview it is relative to the UIButton on the top left which is not what I want. I want the UICollectionView to have fixed space to the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the navigation bar is added, the UICollectionView gets "pushed" down but its height remains the same.

You need to add a layout constraint that will cause the UICollectionView to reduce height when adding the navigation bar. The constraint should be something along the lines of "bottom space to bottom layout guide = 0"

Comment: Here is what happened after I added the constraints: If I only add the constraint to the bottom, I will be able to see the entire items when I scroll down. But then the segmented control and the UIButton will be covered by the UINavigationBar. But if I also add constraint to the top, (top space to top = 0), I won't be able to see the bottom items when scroll down, then this will be the same effect as setting no constraints.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

Try to define the constraints as follows to consider the Navigation Bar (this should work even with autorotation, when the status bar can change in height) It also considers the chante in iOS 11 for the safeArea.

```
let collectionView = UICollectionView()
self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    let safeArea = self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeArea.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
} else {
    let topGuide = self.topLayoutGuide
    collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
}
collectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
collectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```